# Multiple Restful Api requests issues leads to duplicate records on nginx server

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, nginx, duplicates

I have been struggling with duplicate rows into my AWS RDS DB. I am running a webserver for restful apis for flutters apps on AWS elastic beanstalk as in the screenshot below you can see after thorough analysis found that the access logs for nginx also recording multiple access from app. These all requests are from same device and from ip (i have removed it for reasons). Such behaviour leads to duplicate of records in our database.

[image: see the access log here]

thanks in advance..

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: My question is how can i know why the server takes a single api call from an app and makes it into multiple requests thus leads to duplicate data in db.

Comment: I doubt the server does this. But since we cannot see the client, the server or even the database... how would we know? What is stopping your users from just clicking whatever button it is multiple times?

Comment: Yeah true, i am suspecting the app itself is causing this. Our team is running some tests. I will surely get back once we found if it's happening at app-side.

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625962/skip-nginx-reverse-proxy-making-duplicate-requests-on-timeout-for-specific-url